# WiFi keeps dropping out but still shows as connected

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I installed Ubuntu the day before yesterday and am still having a few teething issues.

Every half hour or so my wireless connection just stops, but is still indicated as online. Disconnecting and reconnecting solves it for once but its becoming a major pain.

Several times when I disconnect it takes two tries to reconnect and I get the message

> creating an object for path"/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/8" failed in libnm-glib

I am an absolute noob when it comes to all this at the moment, so please speak slowly.

I am on Ubuntu 15.04 and the output from terminal command

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

is

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please post output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" terminal command to your question. Also specify version of Ubuntu.

Comment: will do that now, just a second, cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can install a better driver for that chip. Run these commands.

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

And reboot.

Comment: thats all done, ill monitor and let you know, thanks a lot @Pilot6

Comment: Thanks again it appears to have hit the nail on the head

Comment: Then mark it as solved